# Getting null values in a string

Tags: java

Just started java.
The main code has no problem in it.
The hihestPage and lowestPages both show correct values
but im getting null on the bookmaxpage and bookminpage.
Trying to get the Title name on both max and min page.

```
    package Library;
```

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Library {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int i,j,number;
    int count=0;
    float highestPrice=0,total=0;
    String bookmaxpage=" ",bookminpage=" ";
    int highestPage=0;
    float averageCost=0;

    String Title[] = new String[20];
    String Author[] = new String[20];
    String Publisher[] = new String[20];
    float Price[] = new float[20];
    int Page[] = new int[20];
    int ISBN[] = new int[20];
    
    System.out.println("Enter the number of books that u want to enter : ");
    number = scan.nextInt();
    
    for(i=0;i<number;i++) {
        
        System.out.println("Enter Details of the book. ");
                    
        System.out.println("Enter the title: ");
        Title[i]=scan.next();
            if(Title[i].equalsIgnoreCase("nomore")) {
                break;
            }
        System.out.println("Enter the author: ");
        Author[i]=scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the publisher: ");
        Publisher[i]=scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the price: ");
        Price[i]=scan.nextFloat();  
        System.out.println("Enter the pages: ");
        Page[i]=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the ISBN: ");
        ISBN[i]=scan.nextInt();
        
        total=total+Price[i];
        count++;
        
        
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<Price.length;i++) {
        if(Price[i]>highestPrice)
            highestPrice = Price[i];
    }

    
    float lowestPrice= Price[0];
    for(i=0;i<Price.length;i++) {
        if(lowestPrice<Price[i])
            lowestPrice = Price[i];
            
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<Page.length;i++) {
        if(Page[i]>highestPage)
            highestPage = Page[i];
        bookmaxpage=Title[i];
            
    }
    
    int lowestPage= Page[0];
    for(i=0;i<Page.length;i++) {
        if(lowestPage<Page[i])
            lowestPage = Page[i];

        bookminpage=Title[i];
    }
        
    
    averageCost = total / number;
            
    
    
    
    System.out.println("Title \t\t Author \t\t Publisher \t\t Price \t Pages \t ISBN");
    System.out.println("======\t\t ====== \t\t ========= \t\t ===== \t ===== \t ====");
    for(i=0;i<number;i++) {
        
            System.out.println(Title[i] +" \t\t "+ Author[i] +" \t\t\t "+ Publisher[i] +" \t\t\t "+ Price[i] +" \t "+ Page[i] +" \t "+ ISBN[i]);
    }
    

    System.out.println("\n\n\n\nTotals ");
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Total number of books : " + count);
    System.out.println("Total cost of books : " + total);
    System.out.println("Maximum cost of a book : " + highestPrice);
    System.out.println("Minimum cost of a book : " + lowestPrice);
    System.out.println(bookmaxpage + " has the highest number of pages :" + highestPage);
    System.out.println(bookminpage + " has the lowest number of pages :" + lowestPage);
    System.out.println("Average Cost of books : " + averageCost);
}
```

}

Outcome : null has the maximum pages : 280.
Looking for : Example has the maximum pages : 280

Comment: what are the contents of your title and page array. Also please correct any compilation errors in the posted code (`bookminpage` doesn't seem to be declared)

Comment: ty for correcting.
String Title[] = new String[20];
int Page[] = new int[20];
this is the declaration.

Comment: Make sure you edit your post with additions, not just add them in the comments!

Comment: What are the contents of `Title` and `Page`?

Comment: Also you must be populating these arrays somewhere? Is so include that as well!

Comment: As @HenryTwist said you might not be populating the `Title` array and hence the null

Comment: Sorry am not familiar with what u are refering to population. can u please specify?

Comment: Have you got any code that fills the arrays with any data? Like `Title[0] = "string";`?

Comment: im using Title[i]=scan.next();

Comment: Can you post your full code in your question? It's very difficult to help you with random snippets!

Comment: updated it with the full code

Comment: Are you always inputting 20 books? Otherwise I can see the issue!

Comment: How to you know there is a `Page[i]` that is more than `0`? Try `int highestPage = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` instead.

Comment: no im only inputing 1-4 while writting the code. But the i have to input 20 book later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with this code, but the one you've specifically pointed out is coming from the loops where you assign `bookminpage` and `bookmaxpage`.

Because you are initialising your arrays to have 20 elements, the loops are running all the way until `i = 19`, so unless you input exactly 20 books, you are setting `bookminpage = Title[19] = null`.

I would recommend initialising your arrays *after* you've asked how many books there are going to be.

---

I also think you are missing some braces on your `if` statements. If you have something like this

```
if(condition)
    statement1;
statement2;
```

then only `statement1` is in the `if` block.

---

As a side note I would research into some Java naming conventions, variable names should almost always be in `camelCase`.

Comment: so should i change the ....[20] arrays to the number that the user has input in int number?

Comment: Exactly, not having the arrays the correct size would even result in a crash if you inputted more than 20 books, fixed size arrays should be used with caution.

Comment: Did not know that it would create an error like that. Thank u very much for ur time.

Comment: No problem, I've also added another clarification on something you might be misunderstanding?

Comment: Wouldn’t putting the ‘bookminpage = title [i]’ inside the if statement fix the null problem? If there is only 15 books, book 18 can’t be bigger, and therefore won’t assign null to bookminpage.

Comment: Yes that's true because uninitialised elements in `Page` would default to `0`.

Comment: However that's obviously just a bug waiting to happen if anything about the implementation changes in the future, and it won't fix the crash that would result from having more than 20 books.

Comment: That’s true, but is there a way to increase the number by code? To have to count the amount of books you have every time you want to scan a few seems annoying.

Comment: In that case you can use a dynamic array instead, then you can keep adding to the array during the input loop. Then break the loop based on a certain input.